# Are there any good controls available for Dynamics CRM 2011 developers?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Rather than spend a huge amount of time trying to recreate the controls (grid, etc.) in CRM2011, I'd like to buy some reusable controls. Can anyone suggest a supplier that has some good ones?

### EDIT

I'd like the controls to work with all hosting variations, which means ideally they would be HTML/CSS/JavaScript based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Kendo UI. They have some well built controls using JS.
http://www.kendoui.com/

Comment: I'vd downloaded the demo and I'm playing with the grid at the moment. I'm disappointed with the documentation though (or struggling to find the right bits). Can you point me to anywhere where there is a description of how to change the formatting of things like fonts, colours, row heights, etc?

Comment: BTW, +1 for now, will mark as correct answer if I can get the styling working to look like CRM.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on web resources, jQueryUI or Telerik ASP.Net Ajax Controls may help you.